# How to create html table including images with R (via relative path or inserted - base64)?

Tags: html, r, image

I found a solution to this in the past and still using it but I never looked for something else. I would like to share this one and get some feedback from the community about this and if better solution exists.

Actually my next idea on this is to implement selection tool a bit like [editableCell](https://github.com/gnab/editableCell). I actuallz could do it but the main raison to use this would be to use copy paste to paste the picture somewhere else as they are positioned. Unfortunately it does not copy the picture.

I have a list of jpeg with a specific name:

```
   010003000Color3_0.jpg
   010003000Color3_1.jpg
   010003000Color3_2.jpg
```

I need to get the information from those names are create a grid of those pictures depending on the information contained.

E.g. here I have a name corresponding to _.jpg

Here the complete code, I let you go through it. Read the comments that are partly explaining it.

```
  # Setup -------------------------------------------------------------------


    library(data.table)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tableHTML)
    library(knitr)
    wd <- "C:/Users/gravier/Downloads/Example_Yann_Html/Jpeg"



  # Function ----------------------------------------------------------------



    addimgbalise <- function(vect, pisize=200) {
      # to add a html balise with a pixel size for the image
      vect <- paste0("<img src='", vect,"' width=", pisize, "/>")
      return(vect)

    }

    write.html.link <- function(data,
                                filename,
                                caption = filename,
                                wdfunction,
                                color.bg = "#00000",
                                color.line = "#b4bac4",
                                color.text = "#b4bac4",
                                font.size = "8px",
                                font.family = "Arial",
                                text.align = "center") {

      # permit to write a html table with a local link to click


      tabhtml <- tableHTML(data,
                           rownames = FALSE,
                           caption = caption,
                           theme="default") %>%
        add_css_table(css = list('border', color.line)) %>%
        add_css_table(css = list('text-align', text.align)) %>%
        add_css_table(css = list('font-family', font.family)) %>%
        add_css_table(css = list('font-size', font.size)) %>%
        add_css_table(css = list('color', color.text))

      write_tableHTML(tabhtml, file = paste0(wdfunction, "/", filename, ".html"))
      # unfortunately write_tableHTML has been changed in the past and is not write the '<' '>' characters of the addimgbalise function, so we have to read again the html and exchange those characters again
      temp <- suppressWarnings(readLines(paste0(wdfunction, "/", filename, ".html")))
      temp <- gsub( "&#62;", ">", temp)
      temp <-  gsub( "&#60;", "<", temp)
      temp <- c("<body bgcolor='", color.bg, "'>", temp)
      writeLines(temp, paste0(wdfunction, "/", filename, ".html"))

    }



  # Parameters (where in function normally, but I detail the process --------




    patternlist <- ".jpg"
    regexjpeg <- "([0-9]*)(.*)_(.*)" # this the regex expression regarding the name of the files
    regexposID <- "\\1" # position of the different variable I want to extract from the name
    regexposWhat <- "\\2"
    regexposField <- "\\3"
    regexposZ <- "\\3"
    formulaPV <- "row+Field~col+What" # then the dcast formula regarding how to arrange the pictures
    pixelimg <- 150 # size in html but the picture are kept of real resolution so you can zoom
    base64 <-  F


    listimg<- data.table(path = list.files(wd, full.names = T))
    listimg[, ID := gsub(paste0(regexjpeg, patternlist), regexposID, basename(path))]
    listimg[, What := gsub(paste0(regexjpeg, patternlist), regexposWhat, basename(path))]
    listimg[, Field := as.numeric(gsub(paste0(regexjpeg,patternlist), regexposField, basename(path)))]
    listimg[, Z := as.numeric(gsub(paste0(regexjpeg,patternlist), regexposZ, basename(path)))]
    listimg[, row := LETTERS[as.numeric(substr(ID, 1, 3))]]
    listimg[, col := as.numeric(substr(ID, 4, 6))]

    if( base64 ) {
      for(i in 1:nrow(listimg) ) {
        listimg[i, code := paste0(addimgbalise(image_uri(path), pixelimg), "\n", row, col, "-", Field, "-", What)]
      }
    } else {
      listimg[, code := paste0(addimgbalise(path, pixelimg), "\n", row, col, "-", Field, "-", What)]
    }

    listimg3 <- dcast(listimg, as.formula(formulaPV), value.var = "code")
    listimg3 <- data.frame(listimg3)
    listimg3[nrow(listimg3)+1,] <- colnames(listimg3)

    write.html.link(data = listimg3, filename = "Picture_grid", caption = paste0("Picture_grid", " - ", formulaPV), wdfunction = dirname(wd))



  # Some other example ------------------------------------------------------

    formulaPV <- "row+Field+What~col" # then the dcast formula regarding how to arrange the pictures
    listimg3 <- dcast(listimg, as.formula(formulaPV), value.var = "code")
    listimg3 <- data.frame(listimg3)
    listimg3[nrow(listimg3)+1,] <- colnames(listimg3)
    write.html.link(data = listimg3, filename = "Picture_grid_other_formula", caption = paste0("Picture_grid", " - ", formulaPV), wdfunction = dirname(wd))

    # base64
    for(i in 1:nrow(listimg) ) {
      listimg[i, code := paste0(addimgbalise(image_uri(path), pixelimg), "\n", row, col, "-", Field, "-", What)]
    }
    listimg3 <- dcast(listimg, as.formula(formulaPV), value.var = "code")
    listimg3 <- data.frame(listimg3)
    listimg3[nrow(listimg3)+1,] <- colnames(listimg3)

    write.html.link(data = listimg3, filename = "Picture_grid_base64", caption = paste0("Picture_grid", " - ", formulaPV), wdfunction = dirname(wd))
```

The final result is like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. You are welcome to answer your own question below ("questions" should not contain answers), but make sure your initial post starts off with a specific question. Then the community can vote on the different solutions and offer their own.

Comment: this'd make a great blog post, tho.

Comment: Totally right :) I changed it the explanation and the title. I would like to get some feedback from other people or other solutions.